# Are there terms for referring to the different parts of a country's full title?

Tags: phrase-requests

Take "People's Republic of China" or "Kingdom of Norway", for example. I can refer to "China" or "Norway" part of the title as the country name (or [geographical name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372426/word-for-the-name-part-of-a-country-name)). But if I want to talk about the political system, i.e., "People's Republic of" or "Kingdom of" part of the titles, what is a word/phrase that I can use to refer to it?

If not, how can a new word for this be created using the '-nym' suffix? What would be appropriate root word to use in this context?

(I know some countries don't follow the above format, like UAE, but let's ignore that for now)

Comment: There may be an existing word, but please note that ELU, like other SE sites, deals only in researchable / acknowledged solutions. Invention of candidate words is categorically off-topic.

Comment: Even in the UAE, the "Emirates" part of the name is the "political system" part you're interested in.

Comment: I don't think "full title" is proper; it implies that the usual name of a country should be a title, which is not the case. Some other wording seems indicated.